# Linker Error with abstract class when including inherited class in another project

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

If I have an abstract class

like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class BaseObject
{
public:
    virtual std::string to_string() = 0;
};
```

and some class extends this class.

```
#pragma once
#include "baseobject.h"

class Point : BaseObject
{
public:
    Point() {}
    ~Point() {}
    Point(float _x, float _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    std::string to_string();

    float x, y;
};
```

Within the same project I can have the function implementation of `to_string` in the cpp file of the derived class but when I want to use this class in another project in the same solution I get a linker error

`error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl Point::to_string(void)" (?to_string@Point@@UEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>path\to\CircleHT_Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals`

once I move the implementation to the header file it's all good. Why is this? Should I always implement pure virtual functions in the header of a derived class?

Comment: When you build "another project" you build with the source file where `Point::to_string` is defined (or its generated object file)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Working with VS I add the path where point.h and point.cpp lie to `Additional Include Directories` in the project settings - I thought this would then include also the .cpp where `Point::to_string` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Within the same project I can have the function implementation of
>   `to_string` in the cpp file of the extension class but when I want to
>   use this class in another project in the same solution I get a linker
>   error.

The source code of the implementation of `Point::to_string` is in some implementation file, presumably called `point.cpp`. That file is included in the source files list of your project. When you build the project, it is therefore compiled into a `point.obj` file, which contains the binary code for the function. That file, in turn, is eventually used by the linker to produce the executable program.

When you build a different project, `point.cpp` is not in the list of source files. The fact that you included `point.h` somewhere is irrelevant. The separation of classes into `*.cpp` and `*.h` files is **just a very common convention**. If you just include the `*.h` file and do not make sure that the corresponding `*.cpp` file is compiled into an `*.obj` file, then the result is exactly what you are experiencing here: No `point.obj` is created and therefore, the linker correctly complains about a missing definition.

The cleanest solution is to turn the first project, or parts of the first project, into a **library project** which gets built into a `*.lib` file. That `*.lib` file should then be added to the linker dependencies of every application project which needs it.

---

> once I move the implementation to the header file it's all good. Why is this?

Because in that case, the implementation of the function is inlined, and every `*.cpp` file in the other project which includes the header file gets it.

---

Finally, note that this answer is somewhat specific to Visual Studio / Visual C++, although the basic idea of the build process is typically the same with every toolset.

Comment: To create such a library project can I just create a new project -> win32 console application -> application type: dll?

Comment: @Philipp: If you want a *.dll, yes, but I'd say you better use a *.lib type.

Comment: I created now a library project and this works - thanks for the help.